# Vertically aligning text and equation in two minipages

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, minipage, height, baseline

I have two `minipage`s next to each other, the first one containing text that describes an equation, and the second one containing the actual equation. I want to align the text vertically so that the first line of text uses the same baseline as the equation.

This is what I've got so far, but as you can see, not really right. The small spacing error annoys me and I feel like I don't understand how it works with the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips} % To omit vertical spacing in the align-environment

\newlength{\equationheight}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\textWidth}{.17\linewidth}
\newcommand{\eqnWidth}{.81\linewidth}


\begin{document}

    \paragraph{Long-Term Load}\mbox{}\\[-1.4ex]
    \settoheight{\equationheight}{$\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}=\alpha(1+\varphi_{\mathrm{creep}})$}
    \addtolength{\equationheight}{-1ex}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textWidth}
        \vspace{0ex} \vspace{\equationheight} Stiffness Ratio, Long-term \raggedright
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\eqnWidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \begin{autobreak}
                \alpha_{\mathrm{long}}=\alpha(1+\varphi_{\mathrm{creep}})=6.06(1+0)=6.06
            \end{autobreak}
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\\[0.5ex]
    %
    \settoheight{\equationheight}{$\dfrac{\dfrac{b\,h^2}{2} + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1)A_{\mathrm{s}} \, d}{A_{\mathrm{I,long}}}$}
    \addtolength{\equationheight}{-1ex}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textWidth}
        \vspace{0ex} \vspace{\equationheight} Distance to C.o.G \raggedright
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\eqnWidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \begin{autobreak}
                x_{\mathrm{I,long}}
                    =\dfrac{\dfrac{b\,h^2}{2} + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1)A_{\mathrm{s}} \, d}{A_{\mathrm{I,long}}}
                    =\dfrac{\dfrac{300\cdot600^2}{2} + (6.06-1)679 \cdot 564}{183434}
                    =304.9\text{ mm}
            \end{autobreak}
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\\[0.5ex]
    %
    \settoheight{\equationheight}{$\dfrac{b \, h^3}{12} + b \, h (\dfrac{h}{2}-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2 + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1) A_{\mathrm{s}} \, (d-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2$}
    \addtolength{\equationheight}{-1ex}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textWidth}
        \vspace{0ex} \vspace{\equationheight} Second Moment of Area \raggedright
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\eqnWidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \begin{autobreak}
                I_{\mathrm{I,long}}
                    =\dfrac{b \, h^3}{12} + b \, h (\dfrac{h}{2}-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2 + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1) A_{\mathrm{s}} \, (d-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2
                    =\dfrac{300\cdot600^3}{12} + 300\cdot600 (\dfrac{600}{2}-304.9)^2 + (6.06-1) 679 (564-304.9)^2
                    =5.63\cdot10^9 mm^4
            \end{autobreak}
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\\[0.5ex]

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Can anyone here help me understand what I'm missing? I thought that

```
\settoheight{\equationheight}{...<equation>...}
...
\vspace{\equationheight} <text>
```

would be sufficient to get the same baseline for the text and the equation.

PS. The `align*` and `autobreak` environments are always there because I do not have full control over the input, and occasionally the equations are too long to fit a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is based on TeX primitives and plain TeX macros only. The basic idea is that each `\eqline` includes `\hbox` with two `\vtop`s, because you need to have first lines aligned. First `\vtop` includes settings of `\hsize` and `\raggedright`. Second `\vtop` includes `\halign` with two columns declared as `\displaystyle` for left and right sides of equations. More lines in an equation must be separated by `\cr`.

```
\def\eqlin#1#2{\medskip\hbox{\vtop{\hfuzz=2pt \hsize=.17\hsize \raggedright \noindent#1}%
   \kern.02\hsize
   \vtop{\halign{\hfil$\displaystyle##$&$\displaystyle{}##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}}

\eqlin{Stiffness Ratio, Long-term}
  {\alpha_{\rm long} &= \alpha(1+\varphi_{\rm creep}) = 6.06(1+0) = 6.06}

\eqlin{Distance to C.o.G}
  {x_{\rm I,long} &= {\displaystyle {b\,h^2\over2} + (\alpha_{\rm long} - 1) A_{\rm s} d \over A_{\rm I,long}} 
                   = {\displaystyle {300\cdot600^2\over2} + (6.06-1)\,697\cdot564 \over 183434} = 304.9\,\rm mm
  }

\eqlin{Second Moment of Area}
  {I_{\rm I,long} &= {b\,h^3\over12} + b\,h \left({h\over2}-x_{\rm I,long}\right)^2 
                    + (\alpha_{\rm long} - 1)\, A_{\rm s}\, (d-x_{\rm I,long}) \cr
                  &= {300\cdot600^3\over12} + 300\cdot600\,\left({600\over2} - 304.9\right)^2
                    + (6.06 - 1)\,679\,(564-304.9)^2 \cr
                  &= 5.63\cdot 10^9 \rm mm^4
  }

\bye
```

**EDIT** OK, due to your comment: there is second solution, which implements a simple "autobreak" feature: first equal sign behaves like `&=` and other equal sign behaves like `\penalty0{}=` and this is a possible break point. Moreover, equal signs are aligned in all equations.

```
\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \begingroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}
\def\eqA{&=}
\def\eqlin{\bgroup\let\tmp=\relax \adef={\ifx\tmp\relax\expandafter\eqA\else\penalty0{}=\fi}\eqlinA}
\def\eqlinA#1#2{\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\vtop{\hfuzz=2pt \hsize=.17\hsize \raggedright \noindent#1}%
   \hfil
   \vtop{\halign{\hfil$\displaystyle##$&\vtop{\hsize=.74\hsize
                 \rightskip=0pt plus1fil\noindent\binoppenalty=10000 \let\tmp=\empty 
                 $\displaystyle{}##$}\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}\egroup}

\eqlin{Stiffness Ratio, Long-term}
  {\alpha_{\rm long} = \alpha(1+\varphi_{\rm creep}) = 6.06(1+0) = 6.06}

\eqlin{Distance to C.o.G}
  {x_{\rm I,long}  = {\displaystyle {b\,h^2\over2} + (\alpha_{\rm long} - 1) A_{\rm s} d \over A_{\rm I,long}} 
                   = {\displaystyle {300\cdot600^2\over2} + (6.06-1)\,697\cdot564 \over 183434}
                   = 304.9\,\rm mm
  }

\eqlin{Second Moment of Area}
  {I_{\rm I,long}  = {b\,h^3\over12} + b\,h \left({h\over2}-x_{\rm I,long}\right)^2 
                    + (\alpha_{\rm long} - 1)\, A_{\rm s}\, (d-x_{\rm I,long})
                   = {300\cdot600^3\over12} + 300\cdot600\,\left({600\over2} - 304.9\right)^2
                    + (6.06 - 1)\,679\,(564-304.9)^2 
                   = 5.63\cdot 10^9 \rm mm^4
  }

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It is really nice. I have one problem that prevents me from switching to this solution though: I am automating documents, and occasionally the equation will be too long to fit in a single line (like `I_{I,long}` in the example). Therefore, I need to specify possible breaking points, but only line-break when necessary. For example, in some cases the `x_{I,long}` equation will fit in a single line and in some cases it needs two lines. That's what I used the `autobreak`-package for. Is it possible to incorporate this functionality in your solution somehow?

Comment: @samirem OK, I prepared second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a much simpler solution, without `autobreak`. I added `siunitx` for a better formatting of numbers with units, and vertically aligned all `=` signs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage[hmargin=15mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips} % To omit vertical spacing in the align-environment
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product =\cdot}

\newcommand\descrbox[1]{\parbox[t]{0.2\linewidth}{\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Long-Term Load}\mbox{}\\[-1.4ex]
\begin{align*}
 & \descrbox{Stiffness Ratio, Long-term\raggedright} & \alpha_{\mkern1mu\mathrm{long}} & =\alpha(1+\varphi_{\mathrm{creep}})=6.06(1+0)=6.06 \\
 & \descrbox{Distance to C.o.G}& x_{\mkern1mu\mathrm{I,long}}
                     &=\dfrac{\dfrac{b\,h^2}{2} + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1)A_{\mathrm{s}} \, d}{A_{\mathrm{I,long}}}
                    =\dfrac{\dfrac{300\cdot600^2}{2} + (6.06-1)679 \cdot 564}{183434} = \SI{304.9}{mm}\\[1.5ex]
 & \descrbox{Second Moment of Area}
                &I_{\mathrm{I,long}}
                  & =\dfrac{b \, h^3}{12} + b \, h \Bigl(\dfrac{h}{2}-x_{\mathrm{I,long}}\Bigr)^2 + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1) A_{\mathrm{s}} \, (d-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2 \\
 & & & =\dfrac{300\cdot600^3}{12} + 300\cdot600\Bigl(\dfrac{600}{2}-304.9\Bigr)^2 + (6.06-1) 679 (564-304.9)^2 \\
   & & & =\SI{5.63e9}{mm^4}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution looks very nice. However I need the functionality of `autobreak` (as explained in my comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380982/139363)). Is it possible to incorporate in to your solution? I tried a bit but failed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Are use of `minipages` *must be*? Without it (in hope that I correct understand question) I obtain the following result:

[image]

If instead `minipages` is used `tabularx` the code become far more simple (and by this concise):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}



\begin{document}
    \paragraph{Long-Term Load}\mbox{}\\%[-1.4ex]

\noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright}X>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}
Stiffness Ratio, Long-term
    &   \alpha_{\mathrm{long}}
            = \alpha(1+\varphi_{\mathrm{creep}})
            = 6.06(1+0)
            = 6.06
            \\  \addlinespace[1ex]
Distance to C.o.G 
    &   x_{\mathrm{I,long}}
        = \dfrac{\dfrac{b\,h^2}{2} + (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1)A_{\mathrm{s}}\, d}
                {A_{\mathrm{I,long}}}
        = \dfrac{\dfrac{300\cdot600^2}{2} + (6.06-1)679 \cdot 564}{183434}  %\\
        = \SI{304.9}{mm}
            \\  \addlinespace[3ex]
Second Moment of Area 
    &   \begin{aligned}[t]
        I_{\mathrm{I,long}}
            & = \dfrac{b \, h^3}{12} + b \, h (\dfrac{h}{2}-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2 +
                (\alpha_{\mathrm{long}}-1) A_{\mathrm{s}} \, (d-x_{\mathrm{I,long}})^2  \\
            & = \dfrac{300\cdot600^3}{12} + 300\cdot600 (\dfrac{600}{2}-304.9)^2 +
                (6.06-1) 679 (564-304.9)^2  
                \\
            & = \SI{5.6e9}{mm^4}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You understood the question correctly, and I think you have a creative solution to the problem. But I need the functionality of `autobreak`, and cannot specify line breaks "manually". However, I did not manage to put an `autobreak`-environment in the `tabularx`-environment.. do you have any suggestion how this can be solved?

Comment: `autobreak` is not so smart as you are :-), so better is manualy break equation (if necessary). With this is less work than measured part of equation width and after then employ it. with manuals breaking you will also use different math environments like `multlined`, etc. shortly, i haven't other suggestion.