# Vertical alignment of equation and text in minipage

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to define a command (`\formule`) with two arguments: the first one is the math equation(s) and the second one the text to be displayed on its right side. The difficulty is that the second argument (text) can be either a single line or more. I therefore tried to use `minipage`.

However, I cannot find a way to fix the vertical alignment: the equation is always shifted down.

I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124082/consistent-vertical-alignment-of-one-line-text-in-minipages): I included it since it may (or not?) affect the result in few specific cases. But the shift remains... I took a look [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380977/vertically-aligning-text-and-equation-in-two-minipages) with `tabularx`: however, it vertically aligns the first line of the equation and the first line of the text.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\newlength\tmplengthA
\newlength\tmplengthB
\newcommand{\formule}[2]{%
    \setlength{\tmplengthA}{.3\linewidth}
    \setlength{\tmplengthB}{.66\linewidth}
    \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\tmplengthA}
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
    \begin{align}
        \vphantom{\ddag}#1
    \end{align}\null\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{\tmplengthB}
        \noindent\vphantom{\ddag}#2
    \end{minipage}\par}

\newcommand{\formuleB}[2]{%
    \setlength{\tmplengthA}{.3\linewidth}
    \setlength{\tmplengthB}{.66\linewidth}
    \par\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}p{\tmplengthA}<{$}@{\hfill}p{\tmplengthB}@{}}
        \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
        \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
        \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
        \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
        \vphantom{\ddag}#1 & \vphantom{\ddag}#2
    \end{tabularx}\par}

\begin{document}
    Let's try the \verb|\formule| command with two single-line arguments:
    \formule{n_1\sin i_1 = n_2\sin i_2}{some text about the refractive indexes $n_1$ and $n_2$.}
    And with \verb|\formuleB|, we get:
    \formuleB{n_1\sin i_1 = n_2\sin i_2}{some text about the refractive indexes $n_1$ and $n_2$.}
    The former is bad, and the second quite good. However they do not match horizontally, although I would have expected it...

    Let's try with a longer text:
    \formule{v=\frac{d}{\Delta\!t}}{This formula is so simple that it hardly deserves any explanation. The understanding is straightforward and the notation are \emph{trivial}. So I'm not gonna comment it!}
    Same player codes again! \textit{(Why is the previous line that close to this line?)}
    \formuleB{v=\frac{d}{\Delta\!t}}{Are you really sure that you want me to comment it? The versatility of a code depends on the date of creation, but reduces with the time you spend without using it. QED!}
    The horizontal and vertical spacing of the former looks better...\\
    Odd, isn't it?
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't figure out why you define two different `\formule` commands. I estimate, than only one would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\formule}[2]{
    \par\medskip\noindent%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
    >{\centering$\displaystyle}p{\dimexpr0.34\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}<{$} % <---
                               m{\dimexpr0.66\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                            @{}}
   #1   &   #2  
  \end{tabular*}\par\medskip\noindent}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
    Let's try the \verb|\formule| command with single-line arguments:
\formule{\sin i_1 = n_2\sin i_2}
        {some text about the refractive indexes $n_1$ and $n_2$.}
    and width formula with fraction and one line of text:
\formule{c=\frac{\lambda}{T}}
        {also this formula is verticaly aligned}
    Let's try the \verb|\formule| command with a longer text:
\formule{v=\frac{d}{\Delta t}}
        {This formula is so simple that it hardly deserves any explanation. The understanding is straightforward and the notation are \emph{trivial}. So I'm not gonna comment it!}
    One more test with multi line equation system:
\formule{\begin{aligned}
            a + b & = c     \\
        a^2 + b^2 & \ne c^2
          \end{aligned}} 
        {Some dummy equations}
    Is the alignment of the equations now the same in all examples?
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
From definition of the `\formule` are removed all unnecessary  codes and improved vertical alignment of equations with use of `p` and `m` column type. The later is defined in the `array` package. Two new examples have been added for test its use.

Ia cases when you have filling that equation in the first column is (visually) not vertical centered in comparison to a text in the second column, you can manually shift text with `raisebox`:

```
\formule{< some equation >}{\raisebox{...}{\parbox{\linewidth}{ ... }}}
```

but to my opinion (and taste) this should not be needed.

Comment: The two commands were in fact two attempts to reach my purpose. I'll try this ASAP!

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! Didn't think about the `m` column type. The tiny drawback is that \\ cannot be used to break lines, but `\newline` works. However, I don't figure out how it works... What is the role of `\arraybackslash`? `\dimexpr`? and why `\extrarowheight` is to be set to 3pt (and `\\[3pt]`)? Sorry for all these questions.

Comment: @OrionW9, ups, in answer is not the last version of code  Now corrected (I delete `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` since it is not needed) and `\\[3pt]`, without it result is more consistent). ˙\dimexpr` is latex primitive for calculation od dimension (in this case width of columns). `\arraybackslash` restore meanning of `\\ `, which is changed by `>{\centering ...}m{...}`. It is obligatory in the last column in table, but it not harm, if it is used in all table columns. INstead of `\newline you can insert empty line.

Comment: I just found that there is still some shift with e.g. `c=\frac{\lambda}{T}` and a single line text. I guess that the baseline is not vertically centered in the math formula 'box', and this induces the shift.

Comment: @OrionW9, in edited answer I improve vertical aligning of equations, ad two new examples and short explanation.

Comment: I checked my whole document and there is nothing else to say but thank you!